# Remove search field on checkout page (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, search, checkout

I am looking for a way to remove the search field on the checkout page on my Magento store.

The search field is in the header, so I can't remove it from there, since it will then be removed from all pages across the site.

So in short: I want to keep the search function everywhere on the site, except on the checkout page.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in you local.xml

```
 <onestepcheckout_index_index>
    <reference name="header">
            <remove name="top.search"/>
    </reference>
   </onestepcheckout_index_index>
```

Comment: It didn't work. Maybe it's because I am using a checkout extension? I use this one: http://www.onestepcheckout.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can remove search field from checkout page using css.

go to your checkout page and you can find body class for checkout page using this you can remove it.

For ex: if you have checkout class "checkout-onestep-index"

then css is below :

.checkout-onestep-index .search{display:none;}

Comment: That it not possible in my situation, since the search field is in the header (which is the same code on all pages), so it is not under the code for the checkout page, so I can't target it in css that way.
But the above solution worked.